# Explain for sms details in android

Tags: android, sms

can anyone explain what is this items come from sms details in android?

```
_id = sms id   
thread_id = sms thread id   
address = number   
person = ?   
date = date   
protocol =?   
read = 0 not read ,1 read    
status = ?   
type = ?   
reply_path_present =?   
subject = ?   
body = sms body   
service_center=?   
locked=?    
error_code=?   
seen=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Those look like the columns of android.provider.Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns, which are base columns for database tables that contain text-based sms messages. If you are asking where the actual data would come from to populate the rows, that data would be present in the SMS message PDU and would be stored in the Sms.Inbox or Sms.Outbox etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you explain each columns what meaning is?

Answer (score 0):

`locked` means that the message cannot be deleted automatically or in a batch operation.

`type` likely refers to one of the MESSAGE_TYPE_XXX constants.

for `status` there is STATUS_COMPLETE etc.